# Open a new file using std::ifstream

Tags: c++

I open a file using ,

```
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
```

I want to open a new file using same ***ifs*** variable , how do i do that ?

Comment: You said it yourself: `ifs.open()`.

Comment: @rajat - `ifs.open(newfilename)`

Comment: @rajat, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ifs.close();
ifs.open(newfilename);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take into consideration that `std::ifstream.close()` does not clear its flags,
that may contain values from the last session. Always clear the flags with the `clear()` function before using the stream with another file.

Example:

```
ifstream mystream;
mystream.open("myfile");
while(mystream.good())
{
  // read the file content until EOF
}
mystream.clear(); // if you do not do it the EOF flag remains switched on!
mystream.close();

mystream.open("my_another_file");
while(mystream.good()) // if not cleared, this loop will not start! 
{
  // read the file
}
mystream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       ifs.close();     //close the previous file that was open
       ifs.open("NewFile.txt", std::ios::in);    //opens the new file in read-only mode

       if(!ifs)                             //checks to see if the file was successfully opened
       {
            std::cout<<"Unable to read file...\n";
            return;
       }

       char* word = new char[SIZE]; //allocate whatever size you want to
       while(ifs>>word)     
       {
           //do whatever
       }
       ifs.close();          //close the new file
       delete[] word;         //free the allocated memory
```

Comment: There are several problems with this, including using `char *` instead of `std::string`, not freeing that `char *`, not opening a different file (which was the question), and using `while (!ifs.eof())` instead of `while (ifs >> word)`. There are some unnecessary things as well.

Comment: @Borgleader: i myself am a beginner in C++, may i know why shouldn/t one use malloc?

Comment: Well the problem is that you cannot mix new/delete with malloc/free (new is the C++ equivalent so to speak to malloc and same goes for delete with regards to free). If you try to free new'ed memory or delete malloc'ed memory bad things happen. So to avoid problems, leave the C allocators in C code and use the C++ ones instead. New is simpler to use as well because it only takes the amount of elements you want to allocate, you don't need to do the whole sizeof() operation, new takes care of it.

Comment: And even then, you shouldn't even have to use `new`, what with smart pointers and containers.

Comment: You're still saying `while (!ifs.eof())` which is still wrong, `while (ifs >> word)` please. Would be interest to know where you learned to use `ifs.eof()`. It's a very common mistake.

Comment: I read it over internet. Would you please care to explain why is it a mistake.?

Comment: `new[]` and `delete[]` are almost even worse than `malloc`. You need to use a proper container.